# How to get more detail about 64bit Xamarin iOS build failing?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uistoryboard, libtool

I have a Xamarin iOS project. I have upgraded it to the Unified API. It builds when targeting 32bit platform but fails on 32+64bit build. According to the output it fails when IBtool is trying to compile Interface definitions. Could you please set me on a track of how to get more details to see what needs to be fixed in the those storyboards? The error I get is:

```
Error executing tool '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool': Argument cannot be null. Parameter name: unformatted (MyApp.iOS)
```

And the output is:

```
Building target "_CoreCompileInterfaceDefinitions" in project "<My project's .csproj>" ("/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets"); "_CompileInterfaceDefinitions" depends on it. 
Target _CoreCompileInterfaceDefinitions:
Task "IBTool"
    Using task IBTool from Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.IBTool, Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks, Version=1.0.5595.8224, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
    IBTool Task
      AppManifest: Info.plist
      InterfaceDefinitions:
        Main.storyboard
        MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard
      IntermediateOutputPath: obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/
      IsWatchApp: False
      Platform: iPhoneSimulator
      ProjectDir: <My project path>
      ResourcePrefix: Resources
      SdkBinPath: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk/Developer/usr/bin
      SdkRoot: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk
      SdkVersion: 8.3
    Tool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool execution started with arguments: --errors --warnings --notices --output-format xml1 --minimum-deployment-target 7.0 --target-device iphone --auto-activate-custom-fonts --sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk --compilation-directory <My project path>/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/ibtool <My project path>/Main.storyboard /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets: error : Error executing tool '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool': Argument cannot be null. Parameter name: unformatted
Task "IBTool" execution -- FAILED
```

Please let me know if there is any more details I can add to the post.

Answer (score 0):

The Xamarin Studio build on Mac still failed with an error:

```
Error executing tool '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool': Argument cannot be null. Parameter name: unformatted (MyApp.iOS)
```

To get more details I tried to run in Terminal:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --output-format xml1 --minimum-deployment-target 7.0 --target-device iphone --auto-activate-custom-fonts --sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk --compilation-directory /MyProjectPath/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/ibtool /MyProjectPath/Main.storyboard
```

Terminal printed the plist with warnings consistent with the Xcode designer but before that it gave this error:

```
nwi_state: registration failed (1000000) Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool ***storageTaskManagerExistsWithIdentifier:withIdentifier failed: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4099.)" (The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated.) {NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated.}; { NSDebugDescription = "The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated."; }
```

After I have the output from Terminal I tried to run the build in Xamarin again and it worked. I tried to switch build configurations and branches and was able to recreate the first error, followed by the Terminal error followed by the successful build in Xamarin.

Sorry for the format of this question/answer

Comment: This is a bug when parsing the output from the `ibtool` command. Please file a bug (http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) with a test case and we'll fix it (and hopefully come up with a workaround as well).

Comment: Added on [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=30221). Thank you for looking into it.